# What is the correct way to use Spring MVC and JPA to update a model?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am using SpringMVC and SpringJPA. And I prefer to use REST style even I am not developing a webservice.

In the frontend I am using Thymeleaf, in the backend I have an entity/model Project like:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "projects")
    public class Project extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7075433538058077502L;

        @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
        @NotBlank
        private String name;

        @NotNull
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private ProjectCategory category;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @NotNull
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
        private Date startDate;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @NotNull
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
        private Date endDate;
```

In the AbstractPersistable, the setId method is protected, so I can't set id directory to this entity. (I know I can overwrite the setId method, but I think this is not correct way to do operation on id , there must be some reasons why SpringJPA defined setId method as protected.)

My controller is like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("project", projectService.find(id));
        return "projects/edit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ModelAndView update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @Valid Project project, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirect) {           

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("projects/edit");
        }

        try {
            projectService.update(project);
            logger.info(project.getName() + " project has been updated.");
            redirect.addFlashAttribute(GLOBAL_MESSAGE, "Project updated successfully.");
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("projects/edit");
            view.addObject(BUSINESS_ERROR, e.getMessage());
            return view;
        }

        return new ModelAndView(redirectTo("/projects"));
    }
```

Right now, in my controller, the Project object's id can't be set by SpringMVC. One issue is that, if there are some errors in the BindingResult, I need to forward the request to 'projects/edit' view with a Project object without id value to let user input the correct project information.

My view form is like:

```
<form id="project-form" th:action="@{'/projects/' + ${project.id}}" th:object="${project}" th:method="put" class="form-horizontal">
</form>
```

Then the action attribute in form tag will not have project's id value. The user can't resubmit the form after correct the errors since the action is /projects/null

How to use SpringMVC, SpringJPA and REST style in a correct way? For me, are there any misunderstanding about SpringMVC API?

Are there any examples and open source projects which have a whole CRUD for SpringMVC and SpringJPA?

Comment: What is the purpose of this abstract class? It seems like overkill for most scenarios I can think of.

Comment: This abstract is from Spring JPA. I think we should not modify the ID directly since an entity should be managed by EntityManager.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing this problem as well. It seems there are two methods:

1. Overwriting setId (as you've mentioned)
2. Invoke setId within POST/PUT method in your controller class (you have the ID in your path).

I've overwritten my setId ;)

EDIT:

OK after a fight with other forms I've got a nice solution. I've used a binder. In the controller class I've initialized it:

```
    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Player.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            @Override
            public void setAsText(String text) {
                Player custom = repositoryPlayerService.findById(Integer.parseInt(text));
                setValue(custom);
            }
        });
     }
```

In my JSP within FORM tag:

```
      <form:form id="updatePlayerForm" action='' modelAttribute="player" method="post">
      ....
     <input id="player" type="hidden" name="player" value="${player.id}" />
     ....
     </form:form>
```

In this way you'll get an entity (od data object you're using) with an ID filled out in your POST method in controller.

Comment: I am using SessionAttribute and ModelAttribute to binding the ID to my model. After the form is submitted, SessionStatus.setComplete() will be called. This is my solution.

Comment: Hmmm... in this case the information about ID is doubled. You don't need another session attribute with an ID while having your ID in your @PathVariable("id").